# How to reduce the size of Qt build?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, compilation, hard-drive

I'm trying to build Qt with visual studio (2010), but the build has so far taken up over 16GB of my tiny hard drive.  I've already uninstalled practically every program I have.

Is there any way I can compile qt without it hogging so much space, yet still get every feature? And once the build completes, will the unrequired files clear up, or do I have to do that manually?  How big will the build be (as said earlier, I've already reached 16+ GB)?

I'm new to this, so please speak in layman's terms. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with 40-50GB of free space. The build generates a lot of temporary files which you can clean later manually.

If that is too much for your computer, get an external harddisk. 1000GB should be less than $100.

Comment: Does the build occur entirely in C:\Qt\some-release\qt (and not some-release\bin)? If so, I can build on my external and move that cleaned up qt build folder back to C:, correct?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure when using VisualStudio; I'm using Linux and build from the command line. There, I can specify a different folder for generated files (incl. temp. ones and deliverables).

Comment: @ladaghini: you can't build in one place and then copy it elsewhere as there are a number of paths hardwired into the Qt build tools.  I would suggest getting an extra HD as Aaran has said.  If you are building Qt often then a 1000rpm drive is well worth the modest cost.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it's size by avoiding Qt-WebKit,etc(if you want). Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112972/how-to-compile-qt-as-static)