# Qt4 configure parameters and library size

Tags: c++, qt4

Im going to build a minimalist static qt4 library and i wonder wheather if use `-no-ssse3`, `-no-mmx`, `-no-3dnow` or `-qt-libpng` instead of `-system-libpng` will reduce library size?

**Update:**
can anyone explain me what `-no-incredibuild-xge` parameter do?

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/configure-options.html

and i quote

> Do not add IncrediBuild XGE distribution commands to custom build
>   steps.

Comment: I have readed this but i don't know if i use above options will reduce library size?

Comment: i think that only if you try this you will get a response.

Comment: Once start compile this huge library, it take nearly 1 hour on my conputer :-|

Comment: i don't think that finding a person with the same problem will require less time, but you can find some tips around the web http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112972/how-to-compile-qt-as-static or http://www.google.com/#q=qt+compile+lib+tips+reduce+size