# Which parts can I make, or nomake, while building Qt from source?

Tags: c++, qt, build, qt5, qmake

I downloaded `qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7.tar.xz` which containts a README which says:

```
See output of `./configure -help' for documentation on various options to configure.
```

That output includes the following:

```
Component selection:

  -make <part> ......... Add <part> to the list of parts to be built.
                         Specifying this option clears the default list first.
                         [libs and examples, also tools if not cross-building,
                         also tests if -developer-build]
  -nomake <part> ....... Exclude <part> from the list of parts to be built.
```

1. How can I find the names which can be used as `part`?

From [How to compile Qt as static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112972/how-to-compile-qt-as-static), I can see some options are

```
-nomake demos -nomake tools
```

2. What about `-no-webkit -no-script`, is this the same as `-nomake-webkit -nomake-script`?

I tried the following and got an error related to `-no-webkit`:

```
$ ./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -release -no-webkit -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -nomake demos -nomake tools -nomake examples
+ cd qtbase
+ /home/user/Downloads/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase/configure -top-level -prefix /home/user/Downloads/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase -opensource -release -no-webkit -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -nomake demos -nomake tools -nomake examples
Creating qmake...
............................................................................................Done.
Info: creating super cache file /home/user/Downloads/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/.qmake.super
Info: creating cache file /home/user/Downloads/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/.qmake.cache
ERROR: Unknown command line option '-no-webkit'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Qt 6 now explicitly spells out the allowed values in the configure --help output.
You can find this located at the base of the qtbase repository in the [config_help.txt](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/config_help.txt?h=6.2#n176) file. Make sure you have the Qt 6 version of the sources - either an expanded Qt 6 source tarball or git module checked out to a 6.x branch or tag. Below is the value:

```
  -make <part> ......... Add <part> to the list of parts to be built.
                         Specifying this option clears the default list first.
                         (allowed values: libs, tools, examples, tests,
                         benchmarks, manual-tests, minimal-static-tests)
                         [default: libs and examples, also tools if not
                         cross-building, also tests if -developer-build]
```

For Qt 5, you can see the acceptable values in [configure.json](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/configure.json?h=5.15#n97) located at the base of the qtbase git module directory. Make sure you have the Qt 5 version of the sources - either an expanded Qt 5 source tarball or git module checked out to a 5.x branch or tag. Below is the value:

```
    "make": { "type": "addString", "values": [ "examples", "libs", "tests", "tools" ] },
```

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.qt.io/qbs/qt-modules.html

axcontainer
axserver
concurrent
core
dbus
declarative
designer
enginio
gui
help
multimedia
multimediawidgets
network
opengl
phonon
printsupport
quick
quickcontrols2
qml
qmltest
script
scxml
sql
svg
testlib
webkit
webkitwidgets
widgets
xml
xmlpatterns

Comment: This is incorrect. This is a list of Qt modules. Qt modules are not the 'parts' that the command line option -make is referring to. I do not find a comprehensive list of these parts, so I'm not sure the answer myself.